# Grouping by titles that are the same with the same (and then different) composers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two database tables,

```
PIECE (PNo, CNo, Title, Tune, Opus)
```

and

```
COMPOSER (CNO, LAST, FIRST, BORN, DIED)
```

are the ones I'm using for this query.

I need to Select Titles that are the same and with the same Composer. I need to list the titles and the number of versions of each. The next question requires the same listing if the Composers are different.

I tried:

```
SELECT TITLE, COUNT(*) 
FROM PIECE, COMPOSER
WHERE PIECE.CNo = COMPOSER.CNo
GROUP BY TITLE 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Something is wrong with that query though. I am using SQLPLUS. Any help is appreciated.

The query for the question before it was to answer this:
"Different music pieces (with different PNo) may have the exact same title, list the titles of these music pieces. List these music titles, along with the number of versions (of music pieces) there are sharing the same title."

I used:

```
SELECT TITLE, COUNT(*) 
FROM PIECE
GROUP BY TITLE 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Comment: You should add an example of data, expected output vs. actual output. It would be even better if you'll use http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: can you tell, what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: It's not an error so much as it's not correct information. I need to print the titles that are same in the database more than once (they have different PNo) only if the composers of those different titles pieces are the same.

Comment: @CSprung Can you follow alfasin's suggestion and update the question with exapmle data, current results, and the resutls you want?

Comment: I tried adding images of the results from the query I just posted, but I can't post images. The titles that I know are duplicated are "Symphonie Nr. 2," "Hornkonzert Es-dur," and "Concerto in D (Trompete)." I know for sure that Concerto in D is listed more than once with at least 2 different composers.

Comment: @CSprung Can you also include your definition for the piecies table in sqlfiddle?  I have some queries I would like to test before posting an answer and right now I only have the composer table to test on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TITLE, COUNT(*) 
FROM PIECE
GROUP BY TITLE 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
MINUS
SELECT TITLE, count(*)
FROM PIECE P2 
JOIN COMPOSER  C2 ON P2.CNO = C2.CNO 
GROUP BY TITLE, C2.CNO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

We find all titles that occur more then once then subtract the titles that have the same composer for all title versions.  If you want more data then just the title, join back to the composers table to get more details for that title.  We could also consider windowing functions in Oracle.

Comment: @CSprung Given your sample data, the above query returned the only title that has two different composers, Symphonie Nr.2.  Changing p2.cno != c2.cno would not work since it would join all pieces to all composers except the composer who actually wrote the piece.

Comment: How would I return same titles with the same composers?

Comment: The statement after the minus is what does that.  The first part gets all titles that have duplicates, the second gets all titles with the same composers.  The difference is the titles with different composers.  Just run:SELECT TITLE, count(*)
FROM PIECE P2 
JOIN COMPOSER  C2 ON P2.CNO = C2.CNO 
GROUP BY TITLE, C2.CNO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your query like this:

```
SELECT TITLE, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM PIECE, COMPOSER
WHERE PIECE.CNo = COMPOSER.CNo
GROUP BY TITLE 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY count;
```

Comment: That returns the same results as my original query.